# Bad vibes in a company that I just joined: shall I look elsewhere?

Tags: software-development

First of all let me start by saying that unfortunately I have an average of 1 job per year at the moment, so if I change again I have the risk to be considered a job hopper and never be considered again for a job.

Here is the situation in a new company that I have joined:

- The pay is great and much more than I expected
- As a new developer, when I joined I didn’t know the technology that we were working with, so I had to learn it from scratch
- I was immediately asked to be autonomous and fast, even if this was extremely unrealistic
- As a rule, management always prefers a quick, dirty solution that can risk to create more bugs rather than a neat solution that requires more time
- Selling the neat solution to management is rare
- If the quick solution causes another bug, or it is not working as expected, I am often blamed for it
- I often hear remarks, nagging about speed directed to me or my colleagues
- Tasks are often underestimated because management doesn’t see the complexity. Blame can come also from this
- If going for a quick, dirty solution is not fruitful and we find this only eventually, and I lose time because of it, I am blamed and asked to have told this before
- I see that many if my colleagues are working during the weekend to compensate, when in the country I am this is not the norm and most of the IT companies don’t require unpaid overtime. It goes against the country’s culture

The feeling is that I joined a startup of people with a corporate mentality that are to the least very rushy and desperate for immediate results, or if I can think the worst about them they are not honest and they are playing mind games to force their employees to work overtime for free.

As a software developer I am aware that it is indeed of a junior problem to underestimate a task to have the senior telling you to be slower but more reliable, but here even the CEO who is an experienced developer, ignores (or pretends to ignore) this. He asks to estimate bug fixes whose solutions are unpredictable, he is aware that a lot of work that we take is unexpected but he still doesn’t give credit for this.

In the end, the feeling is that as a developer I am not really allowed to grow in a company in which the top priority is given to speed. Low quality , fast code that can create problems in the future saves time only in the short time, and I notice a suspicious, unnecessary greediness. Not to mention the fact that I can get a burnout in the future.

I am conflicted between leaving the job and looking for another one, when this means that I would have an average of less that one year per job if I found one now, or continuing and risking in the worst case scenario a burnout, or to be let go later if they try to find a software developer who can be faster, specially if they are accepting to work during the weekend.

What can you suggest me?

Comment: If all companies you join are like this, you have to question your method of looking for companies. If the recruitment process is rushed or/and by your questioning them in interviews you think they are looking for code monkeys, step back and look elsewhere. Is it too late? I can't tell, you say an average of 1 job/year, but there is a very significant statistiscal difference between 2jobs/2years and 15jobs/15years

Answer (score 19):

> What can you suggest me?

Learn how to interview better.

You should NOT join a company that's not a good fit for what you want (in terms of comp, work, culture, overtime, commute, etc.)

Interviewing is a two-way street. You need to learn to ask questions, that will get you the information you need to make a good decision with confidence. Until you figure out how to do this, it's pointless to quit your current job: you will just end up with another bad one.

Answer (score 6):

No problem is ever solved by doing unpaid overtime. You don’t achieve more, you get less productive quite quickly, and all it does is making you ill eventually. If your company seriously thinks overtime benefits them, then they can pay for it.

To keep your sanity, the best thing you can do is *not care*. That’s sad, but the company doesn’t care, so why should you? Do as you’re told, don’t care about any complaints, and look for a better position.

Answer (score 3):

I can't advise you to stay or look for a different job, because I don't know how important it is, where you live, that people not hop from job to job.  (That wouldn't bother me, if the candidate is strong in other respects.)

But I can give you a suggestion regarding the rush-rush ethic where you are now.  To please your supervisors and co-workers, it sounds like it would be best to work quickly, in spite of the downsides of taking this approach.  BUT it would be important to state a clear caveat to the relevant people, for example, email your supervisor(s) / key collaborator(s) to say, "I understand that time is of the essence in this project, so I'm choosing to crank out my portion of the work very quickly.  Please know that this quick approach is more subject to error and a lack of reliability, and let me know if it would be preferable that I work in a more methodical, reliable way."

This way you'd be on record as having accepted the prevailing rhythm, despite serious misgivings, because you very much want to be a team player.

Otherwise, you risk getting mightily on a lot of people's nerves.  (I call this the "Lose friends and colleagues and ignore people's preferences" approach.  It can be extremely annoying.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the culture of where you are from but if you are very concerned about looking like a job hopper, I wouldn't stress to much about it.

A recruiter wouldn't want to toss out your cv immediately after seeing that you had multiple jobs over shorter periods of time. Competent developers are in demand and I reckon most companies can't afford filtering based on "amounts of jobs had". If you are a competent software developer, you'll likely be invited for a interview.